# Sticky position is not working for Safari despite using Webkit

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm trying to get the sidebar class to be sticky for our webpage here:https://www.amorhandmade.com/collections/one-only-dog-collars  It is working fine on chrome, but does not work on safari.

Here is my css code:

```
.sidebar {
  background-color: white;
  position: -webkit-sticky; 
  position: sticky;
  top: 3rem;
  align-self: flex-start; 
  z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: It "does not work" how?

Comment: It is not maintaining position as a user scrolls on Safari

Answer (score -1):

I like using this website when styling to get a better idea on potential issues with different selectors and browsers.

`https://caniuse.com/`